# Drop Partitions SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, partitioning, database-administration

I have to migrate SQL Sever 2008 database to the SQL Server 2012. 2008 is the enterprise version and 2012 is standard version. As we know, standard version does not support table partitioning.

The table which is partitioned in the enterprise version has 1 clustered and around 8 non-clustered indexed. I need to drop this partition but do not know how. Can someone please shed little light on how should I go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your clustered index the backing index of a primary key constraint? The basic approach is the same (recreate the clustered index without the partitioning scheme) but the syntax to use differs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unpartition a table, you'll need to recreate all the indexes with a filegroup specification instead of parttion scheme. I suggest you drop all the non-clustered indexes and then rebuild the existing partitioned clustered index using `CREATE INDEX...WITH(DROP_EXISTING-ON)` with a filegroup specification. Then recreate the non-clustered indexes with a filegroup specfied.

Comment: Hi, I have done as you said, i get the following error: Cannot recreate index 'PK_Partition'. The new index definition does not match the constraint being enforced by the existing index. thanks for your help.

Comment: @SamFenton, the partitioned table must included the partitioning column as part of the primary key. Make sure the non-partitioned primary key has the same list of columns.